# Difference between context menu and option menu in android

Tags: android

Can you please tell me the difference between context menu and option menu in android?
When I click the menu button on the emulator, is that option menu? or context menu?
And how to invoke the other menu (not trigger by the menu button)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

> When I click the menu button on the
>   emulator, is that option menu?

Yes.

> And how to invoke the other menu (not
>   trigger by the menu button)?

By long-tapping on whatever widget (if any) has a context menu.

Comment: What do you mean by "By long-tapping on whatever widget (if any) has a context menu."?
I have a ListActivity with a ListView. In my ListActivity, I call 'registerForContextMenu(lv);' but I never get break in my 'onCreateContextMenu' or 'onContextItemSelected'

I try click on ListView but nothing happens.

Comment: A long-tap is holding your finger down on the screen for 1-2 seconds. In the emulator, it is holding the mouse button down for 1-2 seconds. Note that for a ListView you might have to long-tap on an item in the list, rather than any blank space at the bottom of the list (if any).

Answer (score 11):

The page on [UI Guidelines and Menu Design](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/menu_design.html) in the Android documentation gives a good explaination of each of the types of menus.

Two line summary:
Options Menu - the menu you see when pressing the 'Menu' button
Context Menu - the menu shown when you press and hold an item.

Answer (score 2):

Google provides an extensive summary of the different menu types in their [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

Excerpt:

> **Options menu and action bar**
>
> The [options menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu) is the primary collection of menu items for an activity. It's where you should place actions that have a global impact on the app, such as "Search," "Compose email," and "Settings."
>
> If you're developing for Android 2.3 or lower, users can reveal the options menu panel by pressing the Menu button.
>
> On Android 3.0 and higher, items from the options menu are presented by the [action bar](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) as a combination of on-screen action items and overflow options. Beginning with Android 3.0, the Menu button is deprecated (some devices don't have one), so you should migrate toward using the action bar to provide access to actions and other options.
>
> **Context menu and contextual action mode**
>
> A context menu is a [floating menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#FloatingContextMenu) that appears when the user performs a long-click on an element. It provides actions that affect the selected content or context frame.
>
> When developing for Android 3.0 and higher, you should instead use the [contextual action mode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB) to enable actions on selected content. This mode displays action items that affect the selected content in a bar at the top of the screen and allows the user to select multiple items.