# What is the difference between Context menu vs Popup menu vs bottom sheet?

Tags: android

What are the differences between Context menu vs Popup menu vs bottom sheet?
and what kind of situations they are best fit for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Option Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)  Option Menus are the primary menus of android. They can be used for *settings, search, delete item* etc. we are inflating the menu by calling the `inflate() method` of MenuInflater class. To perform event handling on menu items, you need to override `onOptionsItemSelected()` method of Activity class.

[Context Menu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html) Android context menu appears when user press long click on the element. It is also known as floating menu.

[Bottom sheets](http://www.google.co.in/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html)  bottom sheet is a sheet of material that slides up from the bottom edge of the screen and presents a set of clear and simple actions

Please read this SO Answer [difference-between-context-menu-and-option-menu-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620191/difference-between-context-menu-and-option-menu-in-android)

Comment: You didn't answer what is a popup menu.

Comment: @dvallejo go through https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html .Thanks for checking

Comment: the difference between them.

Answer (score 3):

**Bottom sheet** is an Android component that present anchored views at the bottom of the screen. It became popular on Android 5, you can find more information in the Material Design [documentation](https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html).

[image]

**Popup menu** is a dialog box linked to a concrete element in the UI, with it you can implement the *Quick Actions* UI pattern.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

⦁ Pop-up menu/context Menu - A context menu (also called contextual, shortcut, and popup or pop-up menu) is a menu in a graphical user interface (GUI) that appears upon user interaction, such as a right-click mouse operation.

⦁ Fall-down menu - move the mouse over the menu to open it. In a computer, a drop-down menu is a menu that offers a list of options. The title of the menu, of the currently-selected item in the list, is always displayed. When the visible item is clicked, other items from the list "drop-down" into view, and the user can choose from those options.